# Setting memory per Spark stage

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Is there a way I can use different amounts of memory in different Spark stages?

I have a stage that is really memory hungry and a bunch that don't need much memory at all. Right now my job is reserving lots of memory throughout the lifetime of the job to satisfy the memory hungry stage despite only needing that much memory for a small fraction of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially enable dynamic executor allocation, and increase the partitioning really high for the very memory intensive stage, and decrease partitioning after.  Unfortunately YARN doesn't accept dynamic sizing of containers, theyre static once requested.  Dynamic allocation will atleast allow you to spin up a bunch of workers when you get to memory intensive part.